# Laravel eloquent "with()"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть таблица с навигацией которая ссылается сама на себя по полю `parent`.
В модели этой таблицы я прописал связь:

```
public function children(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Nav', 'parent');
}
```

Делаем выборку:

```
$nav = Nav::where(...)->with('children')->orderBy('pos')->get();
```

Все ок, только children возвращает мне все поля, **а мне нужно только `id`**.

В документации говорится что можно указать выбираемое поле вот так:

```
$nav = Nav::where(...)->with('children:id')->orderBy('pos')->get();
```

Или так:

```
$nav = Nav::where(...)->with('children'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id');
}])->get();
```

Но в обоих случаях мне children приходит пустой.
Подскажите пожалуйста что не так. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно еще указать поле parent, оно используется для hasMany, поэтому этот код должен вернуть то что Вам нужно:

```php
$nav = Nav::where(...)->with('children:id,parent')->orderBy('pos')->get();
```

Comment: Да, сработало. Спасибо большое!